# If one know the sum of the three numbers but is not able to uniquely identify the numbers, what is the sum of three numbers given their products?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization

> The product of three positive integers is $36$. If one know the sum of the three numbers but is not able to uniquely identify the numbers, what is the sum of three numbers.

If $abc=$constant

then $a+b+c=$minimum

I tried applying the concept of maxima minima

When $a,$ $b$ and $c$ are not equal then we try finding values of $a$, $b$ and $c$, which are close to each other.

$a=4$

$b=3$

$c=3$

$a+b+c=4+3+3=10$

But answer is $13$. What is wrong in my way of doing this question.

Comment: Where in the problem statement does it say anything about minimizing the sum? What reasoning led you to think you needed to minimize $a+b+c$?

Answer (score 2):

Look at positive integer triples whose product is 36:

```
1 1 36
1 2 18
1 3 12
1 4 9
1 6 6
2 2 9
2 3 6
3 3 4
```

For each, compute the sum:

```
1 1 36  -> 38
1 2 18  -> 21
1 3 12  -> 16
1 4 9   -> 14
1 6 6   -> 13
2 2 9   -> 13
2 3 6   -> 11
3 3 4   -> 10
```

The only sum that appears twice is 13. For any other sum, you'd know the actual factors, but for sum 13, you cannot know.

I think your main problem here was failing to read the problem carefully, but I cannot be certain of that.

Comment: There are $84$ possibilities to choose but many of them give the same sum. With a machine is easy to discriminate.

Answer (score 1):

Because  $13=6+6+1=2+2+9$.

Now we need to check other sums.